# ruby on rails heroku restore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I just try to learn RoR from this [TUTORIAL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rch3wJ7dmn0&index=25&list=PLDmvslp_VR0xlwr5lAx2PDsZLu7oIOhpX) and in 25th video i didn't get the idea how to restore my data. Example codes are deprecated.
What I have done :

1 - heroku pg:backups capture

2 - pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres myrubyblog > myrubyblog.dump

3 - on this point i didn't get the idea how to restore my data from dump
heroku pg:backups restore 
'https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=myrubyblog.dump' DATABASE_URL
What does it mean DATABASE_URL? the database form my local or heroku's database URL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there If you had backed up you data with heroku then you can easily restore it there is a good documentation on heroku dev centre [Heroku pg data restore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export)

Comment: Yea i see in 3th step when i try to restore i get the error : pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header. 

That is what i have wrote for restore :


heroku pg:backups restore 'https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=myrubyblog.dump' DATABASE_URL

Comment: 2016-05-16 07:33:12 +0000: pg_restore: [archiver] did not find magic string in file header

2016-05-16 07:33:12 +0000: waiting for restore to complete
An error occurred and your backup did not finish.

An error occurred and your backup did not finish.

2016-05-16 07:33:12 +0000: restore done

2016-05-16 07:33:12 +0000: waiting for download to complete
2016-05-16 07:33:12 +0000: download done

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111904/pg-restore-archiver-did-not-find-magic-string-in-file-header please have a look

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was a drobbox link thanks for help.